# C# AES 256 Decryption Invalid Padding

Tags: c#, aes, xml-encryption

I am attempting to use the MS libraries to perform XML encryption, but am consistently getting the following error on decrypt:

```
"Padding is invalid and cannot be removed."
```

The encryption code is as follows

```
       public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string key)
   {
       try
       {
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(plainText))
               throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
               throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

           // Derive a new Salt and IV from the Key
           using (var keyDerivationFunction = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, _saltSize))
           {
               var saltBytes = keyDerivationFunction.Salt;
               var keyBytes = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(32);
               var ivBytes = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(16);

               // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
               // Create the streams used for encryption.
               using (var aesManaged = new AesManaged())
               {
                   aesManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                   aesManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                   using (var encryptor = aesManaged.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, ivBytes))
                   using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                   {
                       using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                       using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
                       {
                           // Send the data through the StreamWriter, through the CryptoStream, to the underlying MemoryStream
                           streamWriter.Write(plainText);
                       }

                       // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream, in Base64 form so we can send it right to a database (if we want).
                       var cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                       Array.Resize(ref saltBytes, saltBytes.Length + cipherTextBytes.Length);
                       Array.Copy(cipherTextBytes, 0, saltBytes, _saltSize, cipherTextBytes.Length);

                       return Convert.ToBase64String(saltBytes);
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           LOGGER.Error(String.Format("Got error : \"{0}\" trying to encrypt \"{1}\"", e.Message, plainText));
           return "";
       }
   }

   /**
    */
   public static void Encrypt(XmlDocument Doc, string ElementName, string Password)
   {
       // Check the arguments.
       if (null == Doc) throw new ArgumentNullException();
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ElementName)) throw new ArgumentNullException();
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password)) throw new ArgumentNullException();

       ////////////////////////////////////////////////
       // Find the specified element in the XmlDocument
       // object and create a new XmlElement object.
       ////////////////////////////////////////////////
       XmlElement elementToEncrypt = Doc.GetElementsByTagName(ElementName)[0] as XmlElement;
       // Throw an XmlException if the element was not found.
       if (elementToEncrypt == null)
       {
           throw new XmlException("The specified element was not found");
       }

       //////////////////////////////////////////////////
       // Create a new instance of the EncryptedXml class
       // and use it to encrypt the XmlElement with the
       // symmetric key.
       //////////////////////////////////////////////////

       EncryptedXml eXml = new EncryptedXml();

       string ciphertext = CryptoUtil.Encrypt(elementToEncrypt.OuterXml, Password);
       byte[] encryptedElement = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ciphertext);


       ////////////////////////////////////////////////
       // Construct an EncryptedData object and populate
       // it with the desired encryption information.
       ////////////////////////////////////////////////

       EncryptedData edElement = new EncryptedData()
       {
           Type = EncryptedXml.XmlEncElementUrl
       };

       // Create an EncryptionMethod element so that the
       // receiver knows which algorithm to use for decryption.
       // Determine what kind of algorithm is being used and
       // supply the appropriate URL to the EncryptionMethod element.
       string encryptionMethod = EncryptedXml.XmlEncAES256Url;

       edElement.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(encryptionMethod);

       // Add the encrypted element data to the
       // EncryptedData object.
       edElement.CipherData.CipherValue = encryptedElement;

       ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       // Replace the element from the original XmlDocument
       // object with the EncryptedData element.
       ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       EncryptedXml.ReplaceElement(elementToEncrypt, edElement, false);
   }
```

The decryption code is as follows

```
   /// <summary>
   /// Decrypts the ciphertext using the Key.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="ciphertext">The ciphertext to decrypt.</param>
   /// <param name="key">The plain text encryption key.</param>
   /// <returns>The decrypted text.</returns>
   public static String Decrypt(string ciphertext, string key)
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ciphertext))
           throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
           throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

       // Extract the salt from our ciphertext
       var allTheBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ciphertext);
       var saltBytes = allTheBytes.Take(_saltSize).ToArray();
       var ciphertextBytes = allTheBytes.Skip(_saltSize).Take(allTheBytes.Length - _saltSize).ToArray();

       using (var keyDerivationFunction = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, saltBytes))
       {
           // Derive the previous IV from the Key and Salt
           var keyBytes = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(32);
           var ivBytes = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(16);

           // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
           // Create the streams used for decryption.
           // The default Cipher Mode is CBC and the Padding is PKCS7 which are both good
           using (var aesManaged = new AesManaged())
           {
               aesManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
               aesManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
               using (var decryptor = aesManaged.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, ivBytes))
               using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(ciphertextBytes))
               using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
               using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
               {
                   // Return the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream.
                   cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                   return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
               }
           }
       }
   }

   public static void Decrypt(XmlDocument Doc, string Password)
   {
       // Check the arguments.
       if (null == Doc && null == Password) throw new ArgumentNullException();
       if (null == Doc) throw new ArgumentNullException();
       if (null == Password) throw new ArgumentNullException();

       // Find the EncryptedData element in the XmlDocument.
       XmlElement encryptedElement = Doc.GetElementsByTagName("EncryptedData")[0] as XmlElement;

       // If the EncryptedData element was not found, quietly return.
       if (encryptedElement == null)
       {
           LOGGER.Warn("The EncryptedData element was not found.");
           return;
       }
       XmlElement cipherText = Doc.GetElementsByTagName("CipherValue")[0] as XmlElement;
       if (cipherText == null)
       {
           throw new ArgumentException($"Missing CipherValue in \n {Doc.InnerXml}");
       }

       // Create an EncryptedData object and populate it.
       EncryptedData edElement = new EncryptedData();
       edElement.LoadXml(encryptedElement);

       // Create a new EncryptedXml object.
       EncryptedXml exml = new EncryptedXml();
       // Decrypt the element using the symmetric key.
       string plaintext = CryptoUtil.Decrypt(cipherText.InnerText, Password);
       byte[] rgbOutput = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext);
       // Replace the encryptedData element with the plaintext XML element.
       exml.ReplaceData(encryptedElement, rgbOutput);

   }
```

When I use the overloaded encrypt / decypt for an entire plaintext payload I don't get an error. There appears to be something specific to the use in the context of XML encryption

Comment: Please narrow down the issue: Check whether the problem is caused by `Encrypt/String(string,...)` or by `Encrypt/String(XmlDocument ,...)`. If the former is the case, you can remove the `Encrypt/String(XmlDocument ,...)` part (see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) and post non-productive sample data for `Encrypt/String(string,...)` instead: plaintext, key, ciphertext and all data needed for a repro (such as `_saltSize`). If the latter is the problem, it is not primarily an encryption problem.

Comment: Missing bytes after base 64 decoding, wrong password for the message both would (likely) result in padding errors. I'd guess that a wrong password is the most likely cause, see Topaco's comment for others. Note that this isn't XML encryption (XML-Enc is an official specification), it's **text** encryption. And note that it doesn't authenticate the ciphertext so it is entirely unsuitable for e.g. transport security; it would not even offer confidentiality.

Comment: One bug is the double Base64 decoding during encryption (implicitly in the outer `Encrypt()` and explicitly in the inner `Encrypt()`). This means that it must be Base64 decoded twice in the inner `Decrypt()` (which is currently not done). Alternatively (and probably more efficiently), it might be to omit the explicit Base64 encoding in the inner `Encrypt()`. Then the inner `Decrypt()` only needs to Base64 decode once. A second bug is the `cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()` in the inner `Decrypt()`. Get rid of that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Topaco - you were right the problem was the double Base 64 encode on Encryption. Working codebase below

```
        public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string key)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(plainText))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

            // Derive a new Salt and IV from the Key
            using (var keyDerivationFunction = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, _saltSize))
            {
                var saltBytes = keyDerivationFunction.Salt;
                var keyBytes = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(32);
                var ivBytes = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(16);

                // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
                // Create the streams used for encryption.
                using (var aesManaged = new AesManaged())
                {
                    aesManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    aesManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    using (var encryptor = aesManaged.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, ivBytes))
                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
                        {
                            // Send the data through the StreamWriter, through the CryptoStream, to the underlying MemoryStream
                            streamWriter.Write(plainText);
                        }

                        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream, in Base64 form so we can send it right to a database (if we want).
                        var cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                        Array.Resize(ref saltBytes, saltBytes.Length + cipherTextBytes.Length);
                        Array.Copy(cipherTextBytes, 0, saltBytes, _saltSize, cipherTextBytes.Length);

                        return Convert.ToBase64String(saltBytes);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LOGGER.Error(String.Format("Got error : \"{0}\" trying to encrypt \"{1}\"", e.Message, plainText));
            return "";
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Decrypts the ciphertext using the Key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ciphertext">The ciphertext to decrypt.</param>
    /// <param name="key">The plain text encryption key.</param>
    /// <returns>The decrypted text.</returns>
    public static String Decrypt(string ciphertext, string key)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ciphertext))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

        // Extract the salt from our ciphertext
        var allTheBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ciphertext);
        var saltBytes = allTheBytes.Take(_saltSize).ToArray();
        var ciphertextBytes = allTheBytes.Skip(_saltSize).Take(allTheBytes.Length - _saltSize).ToArray();

        using (var keyDerivationFunction = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, saltBytes))
        {
            // Derive the previous IV from the Key and Salt
            var keyBytes = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(32);
            var ivBytes = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(16);

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            // Create the streams used for decryption.
            // The default Cipher Mode is CBC and the Padding is PKCS7 which are both good
            using (var aesManaged = new AesManaged())
            {
                aesManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                aesManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                using (var decryptor = aesManaged.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, ivBytes))
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(ciphertextBytes))
                using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
                {
                    // Return the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream.
                    return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     */
    public static void Encrypt(XmlDocument Doc, string ElementName, string Password)
    {
        // Check the arguments.
        if (null == Doc) throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ElementName)) throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password)) throw new ArgumentNullException();

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Find the specified element in the XmlDocument
        // object and create a new XmlElement object.
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        XmlElement elementToEncrypt = Doc.GetElementsByTagName(ElementName)[0] as XmlElement;
        // Throw an XmlException if the element was not found.
        if (elementToEncrypt == null)
        {
            throw new XmlException("The specified element was not found");
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Create a new instance of the EncryptedXml class
        // and use it to encrypt the XmlElement with the
        // symmetric key.
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////

        EncryptedXml eXml = new EncryptedXml();

        string ciphertext = CryptoUtil.Encrypt(elementToEncrypt.OuterXml, Password);
        byte[] encryptedElement = Convert.FromBase64String(ciphertext);


        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Construct an EncryptedData object and populate
        // it with the desired encryption information.
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////

        EncryptedData edElement = new EncryptedData()
        {
            Type = EncryptedXml.XmlEncElementUrl
        };

        // Create an EncryptionMethod element so that the
        // receiver knows which algorithm to use for decryption.
        // Determine what kind of algorithm is being used and
        // supply the appropriate URL to the EncryptionMethod element.
        string encryptionMethod = EncryptedXml.XmlEncAES256Url;

        edElement.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(encryptionMethod);

        // Add the encrypted element data to the
        // EncryptedData object.
        edElement.CipherData.CipherValue = encryptedElement;

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Replace the element from the original XmlDocument
        // object with the EncryptedData element.
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        EncryptedXml.ReplaceElement(elementToEncrypt, edElement, false);
    }

    public static void Decrypt(XmlDocument Doc, string Password)
    {
        // Check the arguments.
        if (null == Doc && null == Password) throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (null == Doc) throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (null == Password) throw new ArgumentNullException();

        // Find the EncryptedData element in the XmlDocument.
        XmlElement encryptedElement = Doc.GetElementsByTagName("EncryptedData")[0] as XmlElement;

        // If the EncryptedData element was not found, quietly return.
        if (encryptedElement == null)
        {
            LOGGER.Warn("The EncryptedData element was not found.");
            return;
        }
        XmlElement cipherText = Doc.GetElementsByTagName("CipherValue")[0] as XmlElement;
        if (cipherText == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Missing CipherValue in \n {Doc.InnerXml}");
        }

        // Create an EncryptedData object and populate it.
        EncryptedData edElement = new EncryptedData();
        edElement.LoadXml(encryptedElement);

        // Create a new EncryptedXml object.
        EncryptedXml exml = new EncryptedXml();
        // Decrypt the element using the symmetric key.
        string plaintext = CryptoUtil.Decrypt(cipherText.InnerText, Password);
        byte[] rgbOutput = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext);
        // Replace the encryptedData element with the plaintext XML element.
        exml.ReplaceData(encryptedElement, rgbOutput);

    }
```